# Render Text as Small Caps in .NET

Tags: c#, fonts, drawtext

I draw a string into a larger graphic in C# using DrawString:

```
 g.DrawString("Re", new Font("PT Sans Narrow", 35, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(5, 0));
```

Now I want to draw the text in Small Caps as it is possible in many word processors or graphic tools ... and I don't mean the faked small caps like "Draw 1st letter larger than rest".
Is this possible in C# / .NET?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're looking for, and what you're not looking for? Because I'm not a graphic artist, and as far as I know, small caps is a font.

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson In Microsoft Word, the font dialog has a "Small caps" checkbox grouped under Effects. There's also things there like Strikethrough, Super/Subscript, Shadow, All caps, etc. No idea how those effects are implemented in Word though. Probably not anything that can be used from .NET unless it was through Office interop.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just render capitalized string?
If you need strings perfectly fit to echa other, you can measure size of rendered string, like this:

```
string s1 = "Simple text";
string s2 = "Capitalized text";
Font font1 = new Font("PT Sans Narrow", 35, FontStyle.Bold);
Font font2 = new Font("PT Sans Narrow", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
SizeF size1 = g.MeasureString(s1, font1);
SizeF size2 = g.MeasureString(s2, font2);
Point point1 = new Point(5, 0);
Point point2 = new Point(point1.X + size1.Width, point1.Y + size1.Height - size2.Height);
g.DrawString(s1, font1, Brushes.Black, point1);
g.DrawString(s2.ToUpper(), font2, Brushes.Black, point2);
font1.Dispose();
font2.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
 string output = "Re";
 g.DrawString(output.ToLower(), new Font("PT Sans Narrow", 35, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(5, 0));
```